# Should adjacent magnets holding up a basket be reversed or the same polarity to maximize the strength of their hold?

Tags: electromagnetism

My goal was to attach a trash basket to the side of my butcher block table. It was meant to hang off a cabinet but I wanted it to hang off my table. This did not work well for multiple reasons but did make me realize a hole in my intuition of how magnets work.

Basically I superglued 6 magnets equally spaced in a row under the lip of the trashcan and 6 magnets equally spaced in a row equally spaced under the table such that the trashcan was magnetized to the table. The thought was that I could keep this trashcan attached to the table and easily empty it.

Now I realize there are probably variables I don't know here but what I am poking at is would it matter whether I reversed the polarity of the magnets such that every other magnet was "flipped". Could one configuration here have made this trashcan "stick" better? Does it continue to matter even if the magnets are further apart? Would one configuration have excelled at making it easier to expand the trashcan horizontally without pulling off the whole thing? Would one configuration have excelled at allowing the trashcan to hold more weight? Would it have been better to just use less magnets and have them spaced further?

I am very curious as to the reasonings and forces involved here. Where my n body diagram in my head got confusing was when adjacent magnets started to be attracted/repulsed from each other.

Basically let's say I had 16 of these magnets. The magnets were about 1.5cm diameter and the trashcan was 19cm wide. How could I have best used these magnets to give this trashcan the strongest attachment.

To make things simpler lets say that you can only fit one magnet in the lip so they have to be in some form of line.

[image: Crude diagram of the situation described above]

Answer (score 1):

The physics summary of your question is whether the total force on a ferromagnetic sheet is stronger if stuck to an array of disk magnets with their N-S poles orientation all the same or alternating. Alternating the magnet orientations should give the stronger force.

I initially got this wrong because I was just thinking about how the magnetic fields between the magnets would be reinforced if the orientations are the same but would cancel each other out if alternating.
My mistake was not properly considering how the trash basket steel would shape the magnetic field and forgetting that the force on a ferromagnetic material such as steel depends on both the magnetic field strength and its gradient. The [force per unit volume](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=magnetic-grates) on ferromagnetic material with susceptibility $\chi$ in a magnetic field $\vec{H}$ is:

$$\frac{\vec{F}}{V}=\mu_0 \chi \vec{H} \,\nabla \vec{H}$$

When the magnets are all oriented the same way, the magnetic field has a very long return path, mostly outside the steel, as shown by the H field lines in Figure (a) below.
When neighbouring magnets have opposite orientations the magnetic field follows very short magnetic field circuits with the field concentrated in the steel sheet, as shown in Figure (b).

[image: H Field Lines for (a) aligned and alternating pole directions.]

The above images are from quick [Finite Element Method Magnetics (FEMM 4.2)](https://www.femm.info) simulations of ten [N55](https://www.hsmagnets.com/blog/n55-fifty-five-neodymium-magnets) magnets (15 mm diameter, 4 mm thick, 25 mm centre spacing) with a 2 mm gap from a 2mm thick sheet of [AISI 1018](https://www.tsamfg.com/1018) mild carbon steel.

The results for the total attractive force between the sheet and the ten magnets were:

- poles all aligned: F = 6 N
- poles alternating: F = 11 N

So the attractive force for the alternating pole arrangement is almost twice as strong for these particular parameters. An even stronger force might be possible if square magnets were used to create a [Halbach Arrary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array), where the orientation of each magnet rotated 90° from its neighbour.

Comment: So if I am understanding right. If alternating its roughly the same except on the edges where the fields would cancel each other out. The amount they cancel each other out is inversely proportional to their distance from each other so if they are far apart they barely cancel, if nearby they significantly cancel.

Comment: A follow up would be what about this orientation where one is inverted but in the middle so: + + + - + + +. If I understand right this sheet would barely be weaker than if they were all the same orientation.

Comment: @CalebK My apologies. My original answer was wrong. (I should be careful about answering questions late at night.) Something was bothering me about my answer and while walking to work I realized my analysis was contradicted by Halbach arrays. I have now corrected my answer.  The software I used is handy for simple simulations such as this, once you've done their [Magnetostatic tutorial](https://www.femm.info/wiki/MagneticsTutorial).  You could play with different arrangements.